# Electricity cost of mining

Tags: mining-profitability, energy-consumption

I've checked with my electricity provider, and I have been told the following:

```
Unit Rate (per kWh) = 0.1399USD
Standard Charge (per day) = 0.1645USD
```

While mining, if my computer is using 100w (which is a reading my electric monitor is giving me).

How do I work out how much this miner is costing me per hour in terms of electricity usage?

Comment: Not sure what Standard Charge means... I'm assuming it's the fixed cost you pay regardless of usage. So if you want to keep toasting your sandwich in the morning you can ignore it in the context of mining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic Algebra 101:

```
100 W = 0.1 kW
```

so

```
0.1 (kW) * 0.1399 (USD/kWh) = ~$0.014 (USD/hour)
```

or

```
0.1 (kW) * 24 (h/Day) = 2.4 kWh/Day

2.4 (kWh/Day) * 0.1399 (USD/kWh) = $0.3358 (USD/Day)
```

Comment: Except KW/H doesn't exist. And any science 101 would tell you to be accurate with the unit symbols, including case. Kilo is lower case k. Watt is upper case W (wrong in question, not your answer). Hour is lower case h as in kWh. It's not about being math Nazi, it's about reducing risk of mistakes and making calculations actually understandable to other readers. I'll edit your answer.